# "Learning Node JS" example - 'The super constructor to "inherits" must not ' +'

Tags: node.js

I'm fowolling along to exercise in the O'Reilly "Learning Node JS" book and I've run into an unrunnable example. My code is as follows:

```
"use strict";

var util = require('util');
var eventEmitter = require('events').eventEmitter;
var fs = require('fs')

function InputChecker(name, file) {
    this.name = name;
    this.writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./' + file + '.txt',
        {'flags': 'a',
         'encoding': 'utf8', 
         'mode' : 0o666});
};

util.inherits(InputChecker, eventEmitter);

InputChecker.prototype.check = function check(input) {
    let command = input.trim().substr(0,3);
    if (command == 'wr') {
        this.emit('write', input.substr(3, input.length));
    } else if (command == 'en:') {
        this.emit('end');
    } else {
        this.emit('echo', input);
    }
};

let ic = new InputChecker('Shelley', 'output');

ic.on('write', function(data) {
    this.writeStream.write(data, 'utf8');
});

ic.on('echo', function(data) {
    process.stdout.write(ict.name + ' wrote ' + data);
});

ic.on('end', function() {
    process.exit();
});

process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
    let input = process.stdin.read();
    if (input != null)
        ic.check(input);
});
```

The error is:

```
[user@MacBook-Pro NodeJS]$ node fileevent.js   
util.js:957
throw new TypeError('The super constructor to "inherits" must not ' +
^

TypeError: The super constructor to "inherits" must not be null or undefined
at Object.exports.inherits (util.js:957:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/NodeJS/fileevent.js:15:6)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)`
```

Any help is appreciated! TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is here:

```
var eventEmitter = require('events').eventEmitter;
```

The `EventEmitter` object is title-case, since it is a class name. It could be corrected by rewriting it as:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
```

but that is the obsolete way of importing the `EventEmitter` class for Node.js v0.10.x and earlier, which is only supported now for backwards compatibility. The recommended way to import it is:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
```

and refactor the rest of your references from `eventEmitter` to `EventEmitter` in order to follow the convention of naming classes with a capital letter.

Comment: The nodejs doc refers to this: `const EventEmitter = require('events');` which is the newer way of doing things.  `require('events').EventEmitter;` is still supported for v0.10x compatibility, but is not the modern way of doing things.

Comment: @jfriend00 really? Link?

Comment: The doc [here](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) and code [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/events.js#L31).

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry if I seemed dismissive earlier. I was a little pre-occupied and also I had read the documentation for events recently, unable to recall that detail so I was hesitant to believe your claim, thought you might have looked at the wrong version or something. Seems as though I'm the one that has done so. Anyway, thanks for the edit and for showing me the current standard.